# How to format axis lables to display formated date from UNIX timestamp in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Here is my code:

```
var scatterChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chartr'), {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: data
            }],
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            parser: 'YYYY-MMM',
                            unit: 'month',
                            displayFormats: {
                                'month': 'YYYY-MMM'
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
});
```

But the chart doesn't work. Data is in form of {moment().format(YYYY-MMM), value}. Nothing that I tried works, apart from feeding chart UNIX data, but that way the chart looks ugly.

Here is the short data snippet:

```
2016-Apr: 0.6031746031746031
2016-May: 0.5079365079365079
2016-Oct: 0.4126984126984127
2017-Apr: 0.746031746031746
```

I can use moment.js, I that helps.

Comment: What Chart.js version and date adapter are you running?

Comment: @Jesper latest Chart.js 3.x and latest moment.js adapter. I tried downgrading to Chart.js 2.9.3 but no luck. Also, I tried swapping the order of loading chart.js/moment/adapter.